# Where does the android studio generate the release and debug apk?

Tags: android-studio

I recently generated a signed apk through android studio and I did press the locate button and it led me to the explorer window. There was an apk file there. but now when I closed the android studio and I accidently closed the explorer window too. and now I want to know where the generated apks are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debug` version:

```
project-name/module-name/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/
```

The `release` version:

```
project-name/module-name/app/release/
```

Answer (score 1):

your_application_folder/app/release